# xmlhttp PUT to update the rest service

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, put

I retrieve a XML file from my rest service like the following:

```
   xmlhttp.open( "GET",
                 "http://localhost:8080/manager/rest/beanRepresentation/", 
                 false );
   xmlhttp.send();
   xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Now that the XML is stored in `xmlDoc`, I will change some fields in this `xmlDoc`. Say I make a change through my webpage, and change the the following:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("beanRepresentation")[i]
      .getElementsByTagName("personName")[0]
      .childNodes[0]
      .nodeValue = "John";
```

Now that this change is made. I want to `PUT` this newly changed `xmlDoc` back to my rest service and update it, so next time I load my page, the name will be `John`.

How do I do this? Is this the right way?

```
   xmlhttp.open("PUT",
                "http://localhost:8080/manager/rest/beanRepresentation/",
                false);
   xmlhttp.send(xmlDoc);
```

the rest service is able to handle "`PUT`" by the way.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest

Comment: It seems like you could use `PUT` here, if I'm interpreting what you are doing correctly. `PUT` should be used when you are replacing the resource at the specified URL.

Comment: Dude have u got answer ?.